# Cannot install aws-sam-cli using pip Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-sam

**VERSIONS**

Python: `2.7.10`

pip `18.0`

aws-cli: `1.16.19`

> pip 18.0 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7), aws-cli version is based on aws-cli/1.16.19 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/17.7.0 botocore/1.12.9

**ERROR**

The following error was encountered on `Step 5` below:

```
Collecting aws-sam-cli
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/0a/448016d5004d1353229b6081c7a05d84c38be5bc70db72d0ac366372fc78/aws-sam-cli-0.6.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error in aws-sam-cli setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected ',' or end-of-list in pathlib2~=2.3.2; python_version<"3.4" at ; python_version<"3.4"

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1n/ppy1_69x0890_qjfyl9dpdpr0000gq/T/pip-install-FRmwqz/aws-sam-cli/
```

**STEPS TAKEN**

Using [this reference](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/blob/develop/docs/installation.rst) I performed the following commands:

1. Install `pip`

   ```
   curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
   python get-pip.py
   ```
2. `ADD USER_BASE_PATH` to `PATH`:

   ```
   export USER_BASE_PATH=$(python -m site --user-base)
   export PATH=$PATH:$USER_BASE_PATH/bin
   ```
3. Install `awscli`

   ```
   pip --user install awscli
   ```

   Had to use the `user` flag because `pip install awscli` failed:

   ```
   Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.23.dist-info'
   ```

   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
4. Install `aws-sam-cli`:

   ```
   pip install --user aws-sam-cli
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. Had to upgrade `setuptools` to fix the issue.You could try running this command:

```
pip install -U setuptools
```